# is it is possible to display Audio meassage in android

Tags: android, audio

I have created an application where it will check the battery charger level and display it on main window that battery lavel is somthing percentage..Is it possible to Display Audio play for battery level notification.Can I do this

Please help me

Thankyou

Comment: display audio ? What do you mean ? Displaying a partition ? ;)

Comment: no it means..when I connect My device with USb it will shows battery status..It has done..Now I want it will display Status By Audio..means It will play sound that your battery laval is 80% or smthing

Answer (score 0):

Here you go fella text to speech or TTS

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [a notification with a sound ?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Sound)

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: when My usb Connected then it will show and when My USb is disconnected then also it will show??

Comment: You should register for a usb connect / disconnect event but it doesn't seem reliable : http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/771f07ead3c635c5?pli=1

Comment: Thanks Snicolas@, but How it will get currect battery level from device nas then play the sound notification